# Real solutions of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $a, b, c$ be distinct real numbers. Then find the number of real solutions of

$(x − a)^5 + (x − b)^3 + (x − c)$

I can't understand how there will be any solution. The polynomial is not equated with anything.

Comment: Do you mean "Then *find* the number of real solutions of ..."?

Comment: Sometimes polynomials' roots are called *solutions*. Hence I believe Awesome's answer is correct. See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. I have edited it.

Comment: In my understanding, there are *roots* of a polynomial (function) and *solutions* of a polynomial equations. So roots would be correct.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you equated it to $0$,

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty \text{ and }  \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$$

$$f'(x)=5(x-a)^4+3(x-b)^2+1>0\implies \text{Exactly one real root }$$

This is because the function is strictly increasing. It shall cross $x$-axis only one time.
Therefore, only one solution is possible. Perhaps a [graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28x-1%29%5E5%2b%28x-1%29%5E3%2bx-1&rlz=1C1JRYI_enIN487IN487&oq=%28x-1%29%5E5%2b%28x-1%29%5E3%2bx-1&aqs=chrome..69i57.13633j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) would help.

It is highly likely that this is the case.

Comment: It doesn't matter *what* it's equated to, there'll be just one solution.

Comment: @BarryCipra As long as it's constant.

Comment: @Awesome: I think that here *solution* is used as a synonym of root, as opposed to an equation's solution.

Comment: @rubik Yes. This seems to be the case. Perhaps if answer is available to OP he can verify.

Comment: @Awesome I did not get how $f'(x)\implies$ exactly one real root. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Rudstar Edited

Comment: This is Rolle's theorem, if there are two roots, the derivative is zero at least once in between.